# Can't compile darknet - YOLO an GPU: can't find -lcuda

Tags: compilation, nvidia, yolo, darknet

I want to compile darknet with GPU-support. For that I changed in the **Makefile** the following settings:

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=1
CUDNN_HALF=0
OPENCV=1
AVX=0
OPENMP=0
LIBSO=0
ZED_CAMERA=0
```

I installed Cuda 10.0 (also tried out 10.1 - with no success) and the nvidia driver. Here is the output of nvidia -smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.01    Driver Version: 418.87.01    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   26C    P8    11W / 250W |    438MiB / 10989MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1223      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           307MiB |
|    0      1501      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         129MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and nvcc -V:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

I can run the examples, stated in the documentation on how to install cuda and cuDNN from nvidia, but when I compile darknet, it gives me this error:

```
/network_kernels.o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o -o darknet -lm -pthread `pkg-config --libs opencv` -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -L/usr/local/cudnn/lib64 -lcudnn -lstdc++ 
/usr/bin/ld: -lcuda kann nicht gefunden werden
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:143: recipe for target 'darknet' failed
make: *** [darknet] Error 1
```

So, `-lcuda` can't be found. I'm really desperate right now and thankful for every answer.

Comment: find where libcuda is installed and add that path to the library search paths in the build

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found out, that libcuda.so.1 is here: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and that libcuda.so here: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs    as you mentioned, I added it to the Makefile and it worked!!! Thank you so much! That saved my day!